# How to pop up a new browser window using jquery for each link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, laravel-5

I have part of my view as such:

```
@foreach($trainings as $training)
<tr>
<td>{{ $training->training_type }}</td>
<td>{{ $training->start_date }}</td>
<td>{{ $training->end_date }}</td>
<td><a href="{{ url('trainings', $training->id) }}">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

What I am hoping to achieve is this. I want that when the user clicks Edit on any of the 
different trainings listed on the table, I pop up a new browser window on thesame page containing the edit form for 
the user to edit that particular training. After doing some research I came across 
a solution as such which looks a little bit promising

```
<a id ="link" href="#">Click</a>

$('#link').click(function(){
    window.open('http://www.example.com', 'mywindow', 'width=400, height=200')
});
```

Firstly, I don't know how I can get the url from my different href's above and pass it to the window.open() function in jquery.

Actually I could have just redirected to a training page view for the editing to be done, but the client 
wants all editing to be done on the same page. Poping up a jquery modal dialog with the edit form is another 
route the client would like so I appreciate any ideas. Thus, I am open to two implementation strategies:
1. Pop up a new browser window to edit the form using the window.open() function above or 
2. Pop up a jquery modal dialog with the edit form.

That's just all I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an event handler `this` refers to the element event occurred on

Add a class to the elements since ID's must be unique

```
<td><a class="edit-link" href="{{ url('trainings', $training->id) }}">Edit</a></td>
```

JS

```
$('.edit-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open( this.href, 'mywindow', 'width=400, height=200')
});
```

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, I don't know how I can get the url from my different href's
>   above and pass it to the window.open() function in jquery.

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'mywindow', 'width=400, height=200')
});
```